# Get user defined class in to controller class

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I have a user define class inside my zend application(as default)

> application/library/Custom_/Custom_Test.php

I want to use it in getvalueAction() in side indexController.php

I have tried included following line in application.ini at [production]

```
autoloaderNamespaces.custom = "Custom_"
```

I don't want to use simple include function and I can't instantiate it inside getvalueAction(). How to do that ?

- using netbeans
- ubuntu 11.10
- I'm new to zend

Thank you.

PS: I will show my code bellow for the sake of clarity

indexController.php

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {}

    public function indexAction()
    {}

    public function getvalueAction() {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $numb = $request->getParam('numb');

        $result = Test::testFunction($numb);
        $this->view->assign('result',$result);
    }

    public function inputAction() {
        $this->view->assign('action','getvalue');
    }
}
```

inside the input.phtml

```
  <form name="enterNumber" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->escape($this->action)?>" >

      input a number :
      <input type="text" name="numb"/> <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


  </form>
```

inside the getvalue.phtml

```
  <h1><?php echo "Final value id " . $this->escape($this->result); ?></h1>
```

index.php

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Custom_Test.php

```
<?php

    class CustomTest{

        function testFunction($a) {

            return $a*2;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: you should be using action helper. refer my answer for explaination

Comment: Very true. But I did not able to solve my problem(Though I gave them my up vote). But I will remember that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action helper is what you need.

since you said

> I want to use it in getvalueAction() in side indexController.php

According to official Zend Framework's Website

> Action Helpers allow developers to inject runtime and/or on-demand
>   functionality into any Action Controllers that extend
>   Zend_Controller_Action. Action Helpers aim to minimize the necessity
>   to extend the abstract Action Controller in order to inject common
>   Action Controller functionality.

i assume you want to use action helper, since action helper was specifically designed for this purpose.

**Step 1.**
You need to tell the helper broker where your action helpers are, i  usually do that in my application.ini file, but you can do that in your frontController or Bootstrap file too.

```
#if you are using application.ini, in your application.ini add the following
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Custom_Action_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Custom/helpers"
```

**Step 2:** 
Creating the Action Helper class, you have to make sure the class `extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract` and place the file in defined helper directory in your case it is `Library/Custom/helpers`

and create the action helper like this

```
class Custom_Action_Helper_Test extends Zend_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function random()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

now helpers are ready to be used inside any controller. it may be called by using following syntax.

```
echo $this->_helper->Test->random();
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: Entering "resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Custom_Action_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Custom/helpers" gives server error. Why is that

Comment: have you created the proper directory inside the Library Directory? in Library there should be a directory named Custom and in Custom there should be another directory named helpers? and what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: and where are you placing the code? it should be in the [production] section of your application.ini

Comment: Every thing is as you said at correct place. Still no good. But have one difference is that "Library" of "library" (L and l) wonder whether what is right?

Comment: yes try giving it proper name. and also if you get any error, post the error code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10424/discussion-between-rj45-and-ibrahim-azhar-armar)

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your file and folder from `application/library/Custom_/Custom_Test.php`

to

```
application/library/Custom/Test.php
```

i.e Test.php inside Custom folder

Add this line in your application.ini instead of `autoloaderNamespaces.custom = "Custom_"`

```
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Custom_"
```

Then simply create an instance of it wherever you like.

Comment: I tried this as you said but it didn't work for me. But thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
application/library/Custom/Custom_Test.php //underscore not needed
```

In your ini

```
appnamespace = "Custom_"
```

The class should be like this

```
Class Custom_Test{
 public static function foo(){
  return 'hai';
}

}
```

Then in any action you can call `Custom_Test::foo();`